# Magento 2 update - cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'concat')

Tags: jquery, magento

In my ecommerce made with Magento I have a custom theme, I upgraded from version 2.4.3 to version 2.4.6, everything works, but when I am on the site it gives me this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'concat')
    at jquery.mobile.custom.js:82:45
    at jquery.mobile.custom.js:561:7
    at jquery.mobile.custom.js:15:13
    at Object.execCb (require.js:1696:33)
    at Module.check (require.js:878:55)
    at Module.enable (require.js:1176:22)
    at Module.init (require.js:788:26)
    at callGetModule (require.js:1203:63)
    at Object.completeLoad (require.js:1590:21)
    at HTMLScriptElement.onScriptLoad (require.js:1717:29)
```

and the whole jQuery code part of the site doesn't work.

This is the code that gives me error:

```
var dataPropertyName = "virtualMouseBindings",
            touchTargetPropertyName = "virtualTouchID",
            virtualEventNames = "vmouseover vmousedown vmousemove vmouseup vclick vmouseout vmousecancel".split( " " ),
            touchEventProps = "clientX clientY pageX pageY screenX screenY".split( " " ),
            mouseHookProps =$.event.mouseHooks.props,
            mouseEventProps = $.event.props.concat( mouseHookProps ),
            activeDocHandlers = {},
            resetTimerID = 0,
            startX = 0,
            startY = 0,
            didScroll = false,
            clickBlockList = [],
            blockMouseTriggers = false,
            blockTouchTriggers = false,
            eventCaptureSupported = "addEventListener" in document,
            $document = $( document ),
            nextTouchID = 1,
            lastTouchID = 0, threshold,
            i;
```

Searching online I found that the new version of Magento (the 2.4.6) doesn't support jquery.mobile.custom anymore, so for those who wanted to use it they recommended to add it inside the lib/web/jquery/ folder, I did that but it still doesn't work, I also tried to edit the Jquery code, again inside the same folder putting an older version, but it still doesn't work.

How can I solve it?